# Draw set of rectangles horizontally in HTML page in Laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-5

I am doing web project Using Laravel 5. I used to blade template format to create views.

I take database some integer value (eg : 5) and also get specific colour code for that value(eg : red ,green e.t.c)

I want to draw rectangle for this number and put background colour to that rectangle.
Now I use for-each loop and draw rectangles. but they are drawing vertically.

===========current code ==================================================

```
    <!-- Main content -->
<section class="content fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box box-warning">
            @foreach($rooms as $room)
                
            <div style="width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid #000;">{{$room->id }}</div><br/>
           

            @endforeach


        </div><!-- /.box -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
</section><!-- /.content -->
```

current code out put.

[image]

please , expect some expert help.

Comment: Use `float: left;` on inner `div` elements

Comment: Better than floating, just use `display:inline-block`.

Comment: @Ohgodway Thank you  both of you. It give me expected out put.

Comment: @uma You would do this by using `padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;` or if you don't intend to have padding on top or bottom, `padding:0 10px;`